# Jasmine - returnvalue should always be specified in spyon function?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have defined the following mock class in my UnitTest Class:

```
class PersonServiceMock {
  public getPersons$ = () => of([]);
}
```

And then I have the following unit test:

```
it('cancel - error CANCEL_NOT_AVAILABLE', fakeAsync(() => {
    const getPersonsSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(TestBed.get(PersonService), 'getPersons$').and.returnValue(of([]));

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const debugElem: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-detail-persons'));
    debugElem.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    tick();
    expect(getPersonsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

The question is why have to define in the `spyOn` the `returnValue`the same return object `of([])` as is defined in the function class? If I do not that, I am getting the error `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

I think, it should be enough that:

```
    const getPersonsSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(TestBed.get(PersonService), 'getPersons$');
```

Comment: You are using `PersonService` in `spyOn` but you have created `PersonServiceMock ` . So, `PersonServiceMock ` is not used anywhere. Can you share your `component` and `service` file. There is also `useClass` and `useValue` , if you want to create `Mock` classes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mock service and adding it in providers array, you do not have to use spyOn method.

Just add

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: PersonService, useClass: PersonServiceMock  }
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(someComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        personService = TestBed.get(PersonService);
    });
```

and jasmine will internally refer to getPersons$ of PersonServiceMock whenever a method of component (lets say a method is 'somefunction') calls getPersons$.

Now, your unit test case looks like this:

```
it('cancel - error CANCEL_NOT_AVAILABLE', fakeAsync(() => {
    const debugElem: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-detail-persons'));
    debugElem.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.somefunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```